# txt file can not be created in java class in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using tomcat 6 ,eclipse ee , win xp and I am working on a JSP project. 
In this proect , there is an operative class named "DummyClass" and its mission is to read a text file (input.txt) and create objects according to it. Then I've made an queries over it in the JSP file .

There is a Web-Content folder and the jsp file (NewPage.jsp) and its contents are below:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="actual.Searcheduser" scope="session"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="mydummy" class="dummyCreator.DummyClass" scope="session"/>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>TSBS Telefon Rehberi Sonuç Sayfası</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
 System.out.println("kagdfcg");
 mydummy.readFile(input.txt);  //Line 1
 mydummy.fileCreator();        //Line 2

 %>
</body>
</html>
```

The code raise error in Line 1, it can not find the "input.txt" in the project. I copy it everywhere on the folder, but it can not see the  "input.txt". In order tofind the correct place, I've created the Line 2, it creates a sample "sample.txt" but no file has created.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Shouldn't input.txt be a "String"

Answer (score 2):

First of all this isn't way yo play with jsp/servlet.. use `Servlet` to perform the logic. use jsp just to present view.

And in order to read text file ... you need to write it to accessible place , add more info on dir structure where is it ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 mydummy.readFile("input.txt");  //Line 1
 mydummy.fileCreator();        //Line 2
```

a string is marked with quotation sign at the begin and the end

Answer (score 1):

from the java tutorial on Files

Relative or Absolute?

A path is either relative or absolute. An absolute path always contains the root element and the complete directory list required to locate the file. For example, /home/sally/statusReport is an absolute path. All of the information needed to locate the file is contained in the path string.

A relative path needs to be combined with another path in order to access a file. For example, joe/foo is a relative path. Without more information, a program cannot reliably locate the joe/foo directory in the file system. 
read the entire tutorial at :
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html

In your example you are using relative files so thats probably a reason why you cant find it.
Guessing you installed your tomcat on your computer and are not using some remote instance its easy to store files  in locations like c:\tmp or similar, easy to find easy to clean.

Answer (score 0):

File reading / business logic is a job for the front controller (say a servlet). Never use scriplets in the JSP

Any beans you attach on the JSP should be meant for presentation logic

Comment: While true, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

It is more feasible to write all the business logic in servlet rather than a jsp file.

These codes can help you

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
java.net.URL url =config.getServletContext().getResource("file.txt");
BufferedReader buffreader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

OR

```
<%
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line = "";
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
   out.println(line);
}
output.flush();
input.close();
%>
```

Comment: While true, this does not answer the question. Also, it has already been mentioned by others. Repeating it makes no sense. Just upvote if you find it useful.